# Sampling from a posterior with Gibbs sampling

Tags: posterior, image-processing, gibbs

In an image processing class, I dont really get behind the idea how to 'sample from a posterior' with Gibbs sampling. We have a posterior distribution:

$f(z_1, .. ,z_n \mid x_1,.. ,x_n) := f(z \mid x)$

From Bayes theorem we express this as:

$f(z \mid x)$ ∝ $f(x \mid z)f(z)$ ,

where $f(x \mid z)$ is the likelihood and $f(z)$ the prior, which we are modeling in different fashions.

In a first task, we are asked to 'sample from the prior' with Gibbs sampling. To that end, we sample from $f(z)$ by sampling from its conditional distribution by  updating the random variables elementwise from $f(z_1 \mid z_2 , .. z_n)$.

Now, we have to 'sample from the complete posterior' and this is where my intuition fails. Iam confused as this is already a conditional distribution. Could anyone explain the general approach of using Gibbs sampling to sample from a posterior distribution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what a "complete posterior" distribution is?

Comment: We regard the posterior as f(z∣x). Our task is to use Gibbs sampling to draw samples from that distribution.  The word complete might be misleading here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically and in simplest form, Gibbs sampling would be sampling from each of the full conditional distributions

$$f(z_i|\mathbf{z}_{j\neq i},\mathbf{x})$$

using some suitable sampling order (e.g. random scan).